# Keep proc.stdout.on() results?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm very new to JavaScript in general, particularly on the server-side.  I'm using node.js and have the following code:

```
var results = modulex.commandy(args)
```

Where `modulex` looks like:

```
export.commandy = function(args) {
  var output;
  var pingproc = spawn('ping', ['-c 1', 'host.com']);
  pingproc.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    output += data;
  });

  return output;
}
```

If I want the `commandy` function to return the results of `stdout` from the process, how do I do this?  Won't the `commandy` function finish before the callback for `stdout` gets called?  In the code above, `output` is always *undefined*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're returning the results before the event is fired. The function will return right away, but the event hasn't fired for `pingproc.stdout.on('data');` You need to use a callback. Something like:

`modulex.commandy(function(output) { /*whatever you need w/ the output here */ });`

and then

```
export.commandy = function(args, callback) {
  var output;
  var pingproc = spawn('ping', ['-c 1', 'host.com']);
  pingproc.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    callback(data);
  });
}
```

This will call the function that you pass in `function(output) {}` every time data is received. Alternatively, you can call the callback after you receive a certain amount of data, or once the end event is called.